# How to change the values that contains "Phone Follow-Up W" in variable visit into "Follow-Up W?

Tags: regex, sas

Here, I get a variable named as "VISIT". I want to change all the values like "Phone Follow-Up W*" into values like "Follow-Up W*". Or we can say, delete the string "Phone" from the values like "Phone Follow-Up W*".

```
VISIT:

Additional Phone Follow-Up 
Enrollment
Visit 2
Visit 3
Visit 4
Visit 5
Visit 6
Visit 7
Visit 8
Phone Follow-Up W28
Phone Follow-Up W32
Visit 9
Phone Follow-Up W40
Phone Follow-Up W44
Phone Follow-Up W48
EOT
Phone Follow-Up W56
Phone Follow-Up W60
EOS
```

I have tried code as follow, but it came up with an error.

```
data test4;
   set test2
   REX_Id = prxparse('s/Phone Follow-Up W/Follow-Up W/');
   call prxchange(REX_Id, -1, VISIT);
run;
```

I want the results as follow, that all the string "Phone" are deleted excepted for the fist one in "Additional Phone Follow-Up".

```
VISIT:

Additional Phone Follow-Up
Enrollment
Visit 2
Visit 3
Visit 4
Visit 5
Visit 6
Visit 7
Visit 8
Follow-Up W28
Follow-Up W32
Visit 9
Follow-Up W40
Follow-Up W44
Follow-Up W48
EOT
Follow-Up W56
Follow-Up W60
EOS
```

Comment: What was the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you want to use regex to change first word that equal *Phone* in string:

```
data test4;
   set test2;
   REX_Id = prxparse('s/^(?<=\s)*(Phone )//');
   call prxchange(REX_Id, -1, VISIT);
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want to delete when the term Phone appears at the beginning of the string,  you could do the following:

```
if index(strip(visit), "Phone ") = 1 then visit = substr(strip(visit), 7);
```

Comment: I like to apply strip to get rid of any leading and trailing blanks just in case